# Delete each corresponding row in One-to-One relationship on delete of either

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I am trying to learn one-to-one relations. I am using Laravel 5.5.13.

My simple app is this:

I create a `App\Message`. I optionally can associate a `App\Task` with it.

My goal:

- Once a `App\Task` is associated, if the task is deleted, it should cascade delete the `App\Message` row.
- And the reverse, if the `App\Message` is deleted, it should cascade and delete the `App\Task` row.

However I am having an error on migrate because the `tasks_table` is created AFTER the `messages_table`.

Here is my migration:

`2017_10_15_021803_create_messages_table.php`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('task_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('task_id')->references('id')->on('tasks')->onDelete('cascade'); //// IF I COMMENT THIS OUT THE MIGRATION WORKS, BUT I NEED THIS IN

    });
}
```

And for `App\Task` `2017_10_15_023343_create_tasks_table.php`:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('message_id')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('message_id')->references('id')->on('messages')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

If I comment out the `$table->foreign('task_id')->references('id')->on('tasks')->onDelete('cascade');` then the migration works, BUT i need the deletion of the message when the task is deleted, and without this line that won't happen.

The error I get after running `php artisan migrate` is:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `petfolk`.`#sql-42e8_16f` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `messages` add constraint `messages_task_id_foreign` foreign key (`task_id`) references `tasks` (`id`) on delete set null)
>
> [PDOException]
>    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `petfolk`.`#sql-42e8_16f` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Thanks @OmarTarek for the fast reply and reminder! I added the error info. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create third migration and move foreign key adding logic in the migration:

```
Schema::table('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreign('task_id')->references('id')->on('tasks')->onDelete('cascade');
}
```

It will work when both tables will be created.

Comment: Thank you sir very much, I accepted this answer but i don't understand it. I already have a schema for `Schema::table('messages', `. Moving the schema create right below within `create_messages_table.php` works but i have no idea why, I woudl have expected to put the 2nd `Schema::create('messages'` in the `create_tasks_table.php` here is the screenshot  - https://i.imgur.com/apI7HLH.jpg

Comment: Ohhhh the error is because there is no MESSAGES table yet!!! Not because there is no Tasks table (which is what i was thinking)!! Wow thank you sir very much, your comments to the other solution here were very very helpful!

Comment: Oh gosh I screwed something up. I deleted the database and am running `php artisan migrate` with the 2 `Schema::create('messages'` in the `up()` method of `create_messages_table` but it wont work now. It is now saying `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check t  he manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') default   character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci' at line 1 (SQL: create table 'messages' () default   character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)`.

Comment: `php artisan migrate:refresh` is also not working. :( Excuse this please, I'm fairly new to the world of backend and laravel. I think this is because I didnt create a 3rd migration, may you please show me how to do that? Is there a place to be able to see the order of migration?

Comment: Call the third migration like `2017_10_15_024000_add_foreign_key_to_messages_table.php` and it will be executed after two migrations you've shown.

Comment: Wow thanks so much for the super fast reply! I am very excited to get this to work. I was making migrations like this: `php artisan make:model Article -m` so now I did `php artisan make:migration add_foreign_key_to_messages_table` and then added this second schema in the `up()` and left `down()` blank but I get same error :( `SQL: create table 'messages' () default
   character set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: Have you removed `$table->foreign('task_id')...` from the first migration?

Comment: Thanks @Alexey again for your super speedy response! Yes sir I did remove that.

Comment: In this case, the error should be different from the one you've posted.

Comment: If I comment out the lines 16-18, the Schema::create in the third migration of `add_foreign_key_to_messages_table.php` I dont get this error - https://gist.github.com/blagoh/08981b7947984d1e6d28192d67c66d3d - but i need these lines as its our solution in this post :( This is my `create_messages_table.php` - https://gist.github.com/blagoh/c88243923fd92e737d6e59b53b12972e

Comment: You're using `Schema::create` instead of `Schema::table`. Please look at the code in my answer, it uses `Schema::table`.

Comment: Ahhh gosh!! Thank you Alexey!

Comment: Oh my gosh forgive this please, when I do `php artisan migrate:rollback` it gives me error: `[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign   key constraint fails (SQL: drop table if exists 'tasks' [PDOException]  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign   key constraint fails`. i suspect I need to put something into `down()` of the third migration to `un-foreign` it before the tasks table is deleted?

Comment: Yes, you need to add `$table->dropForeign(['task_id']);` and similar for all other FKs to the `down()` method of related migration classes.

Answer (score 1):

A one-to-one relationship links one row in a database table to one (and only one) row in another table.

`onDelete('cascade')` is used when there is an intermediate, also known as a pivot, table between two tables in a many-to-many relationship.  You do not need this for a one-to-one relationship because the link to the messages table only exists in the row of the tasks table (and that is being deleted).

Try this for the tasks table migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('message_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->foreign('message_id')->references('id')->on('messages');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kerrin, but if `App\Message` row is deleted, how can I make it delete the corresponding `App\Task` row? And vice versa?

Comment: `onDelete('cascade')` has nothing to do with many-to-many or one-to-one relationships. Here's a good reading about cascade deleting https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/foreign_keys/foreign_delete.php

Comment: Yes, I was just coming back here to correct that.  With the foreign key in place as above, the `onDelete('cascade')` will work as intended.

Comment: @kerrin it will still not work, because there is no `messages` table yet. And this table will be created only after `2017_10_15_021803_create_messages_table.php` execution.